# jQuery onclick, select input box and press enter (rendered html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user clicks a html div (#searchboxquicktab), I want the cursor to move to an input box and it should simulate an enter key being pressed so it can show the results just from the click.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="form-type-textfield form-item-title form-item form-group">
 <input placeholder="Start typing a name here to filter listing..." class="form-control form-text ctools-auto-submit-processed" id="edit-title" name="title" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" type="text">
 <div id="searchboxquicktab">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search
 </div>
</div>
```

The search box (#searchboxquicktab) is being rendered by javascript hence the parent and child elements in the jquery code below

```
// Select textbox and press enter key to show results.
$('.form-item-title').on("click", "#searchboxquicktab", function() {
  console.log('search box quicktab button pressed.');
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.which = 13; // Enter
  $('input.ctools-auto-submit-processed').focus().trigger(e);
});
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Is there already a handler for when the user actually does press enter? If so, just call that handler instead of triggering a keypress

Answer (score 1):

Triggering key events, will be received by anything listening for them, but they will NOT affect the input. I've tested your code and the event is actually being fired.

That said, I have in the passed used a jQuery plugin called `jquery.sendkeys.js` (see https://github.com/dwachss/bililiteRange/blob/master/jquery.sendkeys.js) to simulate keystrokes.

NOTE: The `jquery.sendkeys.js` requires `bililiteRange.js`.
https://github.com/dwachss/bililiteRange/blob/master/bililiteRange.js.